# Getting avvio error and code AVV_ERR_READY_TIMEOUT when sart the application

Tags: typescript, fastify

**Getting AVV_ERR_READY_TIMEOUT when sart the app, detail error**

```
AvvioError [Error]: Plugin did not start in time: 'fastifyDecorators'. You may have forgotten to call 'done' function or to resolve a Promise
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/avvio/plugin.js:122:19)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  code: 'AVV_ERR_READY_TIMEOUT',
  fn: <ref *1> [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] {
    default: [Circular *1],
    fastifyDecorators: [Circular *1],
    [Symbol(skip-override)]: true,
    [Symbol(fastify.display-name)]: 'fastifyDecorators',
    [Symbol(plugin-meta)]: { fastify: '^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0', name: 'fastifyDecorators' }
  }
}
```

Comment: We need the code - do you have a plugin named fastofydecorators?

Comment: no, that is default from fastify this the code for starting

export async function initServer(): Promise<FastifyInstance> {
  const server: FastifyInstance = Fastify({
    logger: true,
    pluginTimeout: 30000,
  }).withTypeProvider<TypeBoxTypeProvider>();

  await registerPlugins(server);

  await registerHooks(server);

  await registerControllers(server);

  await registerOtherHandlers(server);

  return server;
}

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to create and start a new fastify server?